# Rails 3 cache questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

Say I want to use the dalli store for caching (fragments of) views. Does this mean that doing something like this will also use memcache for possible DB caching?

```
Rails.cache.fetch("something") { smth }
```

Also, if I do something like:

```
Author.all
```

the Rails console will show me that it's querying the database, but if I run `Author.all` again, it will show me that the results are retrieved from cache. When do I want to explicitly use `Rails.cache` and when should I rely on ActiveRecord to do the caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch and read operations get items from the 
cache store which is currently configured,
for example from the file system if the cache
store is `:file_store`, or from the Memcached
server if the store is `:mem_cache_store`.
Therefore if you want to use Memcached for
fragment caching, you have to configure the
cache_store accordingly:

```
ActionController::Base.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, "cache-1.example.com"
```

It is recommendable to use [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)
if one has large, complex views involving many
queries which change rarely or slowly. Fragement
caching is a good trade-off between completely
static pages (fast, but fixed) and dynamic pages
(slow, but variable). If you need to cache a certain section of a
page instead of the entire page, fragment caching is the way 
to go, as Ryan Bates said in his [Railscast about fragment caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/90-fragment-caching-revised).

Page and action caching are even better, they are great 
for speeding up the performance of a page, but problematic 
if it contains user-specific content. In this case
it is possible to use [dynamic page caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/169-dynamic-page-caching-revised). Stackoverflow
uses a similar technique.

[SQL Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) persists only for the duration of 
a single action.